# Large Background Image Swap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an intro page to my site which consists of a large background image that fills the screen, but when you roll over a certain part of the image, the image changes without flicker. 
I'd like this to work on firefox, chrome, safari, and opera.

I've been reading about image map-image flips, but this gets confusing when talking about an image that will re-size (since it's a big background image).

Can anyone point me to someone that has done this exact thing before or any instructions on doing something like this?

Comment: What do you mean with "the image changes"? It will go up in smoke?

Comment: the image resizes as the browser window resizes. so i can't set the blank div to occur at an absolute point, because the region that defines of the photo will be different depending on how large the browser window is. therefore, i'll have to define the div area in some type of relative terms so that as the browser window resizes, the clickable area will stay over the same area of the photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to your img tag.

Create a blank div (or span), and set the height, width, and position to the region of the picture that you want. Then, you can use the:

```
onmouseover="[function]"
```

in your html. Then, make a javascript function that looks like:

```
document.getElementById('[imgid]').src = '[path to img]';
```

Comment: okay, so if the photo is changing is size with the browser though, in order to define the blank div, i'd have to define it in some relative terms that would stay at relatively the same place on the photo as the photo changes sizes with the browser? that's the part i'm confused about.

Comment: Fetch the ID of the image, and through javscript, use the [object].style = "[css]" syntax.